# Dependency injection (DI) in ASP.Net MVC 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

i was reading a write up on easily dependency injection in ASP.Net MVC 6 from this url **http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/introducing-asp-net-5**

they show how very easily we can inject dependency into project

### 1st one

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class TimeService
    {
        public TimeService()
        {
            Ticks = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        }
        public String Ticks { get; set; }
    }
}


register the time service as a transient service in the ConfigureServices method of the Startup class:

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
        services.AddTransient<TimeService>();
    }


public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public TimeService TimeService { get; set; }

    public HomeController(TimeService timeService)
    {
        TimeService = timeService;
    }


    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = TimeService.Ticks + " From Controller";
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1);
        return View();
    }
}
```

### 2nd one

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [Activate]
    public TimeService TimeService { get; set; }
}
```

now see the second code. are they trying to say that if we use `[Activate]` attribute then we do not have to instantiate `TimeService` by controller constructor injection?

just tell me if we use `[Activate]` attribute then what will be the advantage ?

if we use `[Activate]` attribute then what line of code we can eliminate from 1st same code. thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The differences between the two code blocks are indeed that the first one leverages Constructor Injection to resolve the dependency on `TimeService`, while the second example marks a property as one that needs resolving using Property Injection.

What this means is simply that the following constructor becomes redundant:

```
public HomeController(TimeService timeService)
{
    TimeService = timeService;
}
```

As to why one would opt for Constructor versus Property Injection, I find that trying to have a list of your dependencies clearly listed out in your constructor highlights when a class becomes too dependent, which raises concerns as to what a class is trying to accomplish and, subsequently, makes it a candidate for refactoring.

Property Injection via `[Activate]` [will not be supported](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/28) from beta5 onwards.

Comment: thanks for answer. can u tell me when people select constructor injection and when property injection? which one is good?

Comment: As I said, keeping your injections in your constructor helps with identifying code smells.It also ensures that your object, at initialization, has ALL the dependencies it requires to function properly. There's no ambiguity at that point, either you satisfy the dependency, or your class will simply not instantiate. There's plenty of resources on the matter, if you google "Constructor vs Setter Injection", you'll find plenty.

Comment: sorry not very clear. are you trying to constructor injection is better than property injection ?

Comment: In almost all scenarios, I'd say yes

Comment: **Note:** property injection via [Activate] in controllers also gives you the ability to pull a few select items that are not present in DI such as `ActionContext`, `HttpContext`, `HttpRequest`, `HttpResponse`, `ViewDataDictionary` and `ActionBindingContext`. These become more valuable when you're no longer inheriting from the `Controller` class and making use of poco controllers.

Comment: @N. Taylor Mullen. That is a good point and one that's definitely worth raising.

Comment: Is property injection using the [Activate] attribute only available to Controllers?

Comment: It's available to every class, as long as it can be managed by the IOC container and the properties are publicly accessible (I think there's some frameworks that can deal with private properties but that's getting real ugly real fast.